# How do I identify when other JUnit tests steal my Spring Root Controller?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I have a JUnit test that looks like this - it is part of a larger application.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { MyTestConfig.class })
public class MyHandlerInterceptorTest  {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET",
            "/myrequest");
        HandlerExecutionChain handlerExecutionChain = requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(request);
    }
}
```

When I run my test in isolation - it runs fine.

When I run it as part of a suite of other tests - I get the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.MyHandlerInterceptorTest  ': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping com.MyHandlerInterceptorTest.requestMappingHandlerMapping; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Cannot reinitialize with different application context: current one is [Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [XXX 2016]; root of context hierarchy], passed-in one is [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4760457f: startup date [XXX 2016]; root of context hierarchy]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping com.MyHandlerInterceptorTest.requestMappingHandlerMapping; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Cannot reinitialize with different application context: current one is [Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [XXX 2016]; root of context hierarchy], passed-in one is [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4760457f: startup date [Fri Mar 18 11:01:19 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
```

What appears to be happening is that my test context is stolen by other tests. I want to know how to identify when this occurs and stop it, or at least work around it.

This is different to the other question because this is about identifying the other tests, not blocking with a workaround.

My question is: **How do I identify when other JUnit tests steal my Spring Root Controller?**

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a @WebAppConfiguration to your test class so that it loads a WebApplicationContext instead of a general ApplicationContext.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { MyTestConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyHandlerInterceptorTest  {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET",
            "/myrequest");
        HandlerExecutionChain handlerExecutionChain = requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've figure out how to fix my test - I'm trying to work out the root cause - where are the other tests doing this?